# Hide Numbers from ZedGraph in C#

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I need to hide the numbers marked with the arrow, and if possible, show the blue numbers currently on the right side where now the red ones are...
The red numbers are for the blue line, and I don't need them so I want to hide them... the blue numbers are for the red curve, and I need them on the left side... is this possible in Windows forms?

[image: Graphic]

Comment: Yes, should be possible.

Comment: @UweKeim how, can you explain it or add some code?

Comment: Is the scale always the same for both plots?

Comment: not always, is this a problem?